# React memo creates rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm having an issue with react memo when using nextjs. In the _app e.g. I have a button imported:

```
import { ChildComponent } from './ChildComponent';

export const Button = ({ classN }: { classN?: string }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
  
  const Parent = () => { return (
     <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>Click me</button>
  )}
  
  return (
    <div>
      {counter}
      <Parent />
      <ChildComponent />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Child component:

```
import React from 'react';

export const ChildComponent = React.memo(
  () => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
      console.log('rerender child component');
    }, []);

    return <p>Prevent rerender</p>;
  },
  () => false
);
```

I made one working in React couldn't figure it out in my own app:
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-goldwasser-83vb4?file=/src/ChildComponent.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my issue was that I made a function called Button and returned inside a button or Link. So I had a mouseEnter inside the button which would update the state and handle the function outside the function. Kinda embarrassing. This fixed it. So the only change was I moved usestate and handlemousehover inside the button function.

```
const Button = () => {
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

    const handleMouseHover = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
      if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
        setHover(true);
      } else if (e.type === 'mouseleave') setHover(false);
    };

    return (
      <StyledPrimaryButton
        onMouseEnter={(e) => handleMouseHover(e)}
        onMouseLeave={(e) => handleMouseHover(e)}
      >
        <StyledTypography
          tag="span"
          size="typo-20"
        >
          {title}
        </StyledTypography>
        <ChildComponent />
      </StyledPrimaryButton>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

The second argument of `React.memo()` must be a function that returns `true` if the component *don't need* to be rerendered and `false` otherwise - or [in the original definition](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), *if the old props and the new props are equal or not*.

So, in your code, the solution should be just change the second argument to:

```js
export const ChildComponent = React.memo(
  () => { ... },
  // this
  () => true
);
```

Which is gonna tell React that "the props didn't change and thus don't need to rerender this component".

Comment: Thanks for looking into this however this didn't solve my issue unfortunately

Comment: What you would like is for it to run `console.log()` just once, right? Isn't that what it's doing?

Comment: Yes it is, but my issue is with the Next.js framework. Never had this issue before, really strange. I can't show an example because codesandbox doensn't work with nextjs?